# JPA: Why is implementing table per concrete class optional?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

for a project I'm currently comparing ORM statrategies from `Hibenate` with an own implementation of a basic ORM. While looking through the [JPA specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) I found out, that `Single Table` and `Joined subclass` need to be implemented but not `per concrete class`. I tried to find out if there were any obvious disadvanteges but I can't find any answer to why `joined` needs to be supported but not `concrete`. Does anyone have an answer to this?

Thanks

Comment: on page 58 of the link I posted it says this: `Support for the table per concrete class inheritance mapping strategy is optional in this
release. Applications that use this mapping strategy will not be portable.`

Comment: Yeah, I realized I didn't read your question correctly. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JPA specification the table per concrete class strategy is optional because of following drawbacks:

> This strategy has the following drawbacks: 
>   • It provides poor support for polymorphic relationships.
>   • It typically requires that SQL UNION queries (or a separate SQL query per subclass) be issued for queries that are intended to range over the class hierarchy.

One special disadvantage is that the UNION operator which is needed for polymorphic queries, does duplicate detection which slows down the application.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the following simple model:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType....)
public class Superclass {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String superValue;
}

@Entity
public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private String subValue;
}
```

Now let's have a look at some queries:

```
SELECT s FROM Superclass s
```

This query translated to SQL for `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`:

```
SELECT id, dtype, superValue, subValue FROM Superclass
```

(`dtype` is the *discriminator column* to indicate the class of the entity)

This query translated to SQL for `InheritanceType.JOINED`:

```
SELECT Superclass.id, dtype, superValue, subValue FROM Superclass 
  LEFT JOIN Subclass ON Superclass.id = Subclass.id
```

And finally for `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`:

```
SELECT id, 'Superclass' AS dtype, superValue, null FROM Superclass 
UNION ALL SELECT id, 'Subclass' AS dtype, superValue, subValue FROM Subclass
```

As you can see, the major disadvantage of the `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`: The tables are not normalized and you have to use a slow `UNION`. As this is a 'special' table layout and as you have no advantage compared with `JOINED`, it is left to the provider to support it.

Comment: the normalization is an aspect i have not thought about yet. do you have an example of how this would be problem, though? data in a single table isn't normalized either...

Comment: But `SINGLE_TABLE` has no performance impact (it is even faster than `JOINED` in many circumstances) and is much easier to implement.